# how to add bsDatepicker to the header cell in tabulator

Tags: angular, datatable, tabulator

editor is not working in tabulator and  have a requirement to add bsdatepicker to the tabulator .Please help.

var dateEditor = function(){
  var editor = document.createElement("div");
editor.innerHTML = '   ' 
    return editor;
};

this.addressTable = new Tabulator("#dhl-table", {
{ title: "Status", field: "status", editor:dateEditor , headerFilterParams: {values: this.statusDropdownList}, headerFilter:"input",
})

this s the approximate code structure I'm trying to use .please help how to bind the datepicker plugin to tabulator header input filter

[[image: want to put datepicker on click of this inputbox[1]]

Comment: please post a snippet of the code you are trying to use, or a link to a JS Fiddle. without more information about what you are trying it is hard to give you helpful feedback

Comment: I have updated please look at it

Comment: you need to create a JS fiddle that shows us how your editor is setup, without seeing the whole code of the editor it is not possible offer advice. what i would say is that you dont seem to be instantiating the datepicker in your editor, you are only returning an empty div